# Catch HttpException in time when file upload exceeds size

Tags: .net, asp.net

so i am making a file upload. I have, in my web.config:
`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="5120"/>`
so the file can't exceed 5MB.
My server side code looks something like:

> protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
>       try
>       {
>
> ```
>     if (fupCV.FileName != "") {
>      DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("CVs"));
>      if (!di.Exists)
>          di.Create();
>      fupCV.SaveAs(di.FullName + "/" + fupCV.FileName);
>      //afterwards code    
>     }                    
> }
> catch (HttpException ex) {
>     Response.Write(ex.Message);                
> }
> ```
>
> }

and i can't catch the exception, i still get "Server Error in '/' Application."

Thanx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, after stopping thinking about this, the answer came to my mind. I can set a bigger `maxRequestLength` in the web.config, say like 20 MBs if i want a limit of 5 MBs. And then in the submit event, after testing if the file is in the server, i can test it's size with

```
fupCV.FileBytes.Length
```

and throw an exception if it exceeds 5.000.000 bytes or so.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the request never reach your code, IIS never passes the request to your code because it is to big.

I guess the only thing you can do is to upload via ajax and control the error code returned from your server.

Comment: that's what i thought, so how can i control that the user doesn't put a file bigger than 5MBs?

Comment: You just can't ! I guess the only thing you can do is to upload via ajax and control the error code returned from your server.

Comment: well, now that some time has passed, and a miraculous solution hasn't come, i will accept your answer. Thanx

Comment: @André : I know why no miraculous solution has come up : ain't any ! Cheers